# Error "Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment" when i called method from Presenter

Tags: android, viewmodel

I have a fragment with `updateToolbar()` function. When i try to get my ViewModel, calles **UserViewModel** on this method i get error:

`Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment`

When i try to get **UserViewModel** inside `onViewCreated()`, all works fine. Why it happens? I call `updateToolbar()` after `onCreateView()` and I'm not create any fragment transactions before function called.

I'm started to learn Clean Architecture, and intuitively i think the reason of error can be on it, so i add this code too. I think problem about presenter, but i can't understand where exactly.

---

**PacksFragment:**

```
 class PacksFragment : BaseCompatFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: PacksFragmentPresenter

    private var userViewModel: UserViewModel? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        ...
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {    
        LibApp.get().injector.inject(this)
        ...    
        presenter.openNewPack(packId)
    }

    fun updateToolbar() {
        Timber.e((userViewModel == null).toString())
        Timber.e(userViewModel?.getData()?.value?.coins.toString())
    }
}
```

---

**PacksFragmentPresenter:**

```
class PacksFragmentPresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val packsFragment: PacksFragment,
    private val getCoinsFromUserCase: GetCoinsFromUserCase
) {

    fun openNewPack(packId: Int) {
        if (getCoinsFromUserCase.getCoinsFromUser()){
            packsFragment.updateToolbar()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**GetCoinsFromUserCase:**

```
class GetCoinsFromUserCase {

    fun getCoinsFromUser(): Boolean {
        val userViewModel = UserViewModel()
        userViewModel.takeCoins(10)
        return true
    }
}
```

---

**userViewModel:**

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel(), UserApi {
    private val data = MutableLiveData<User>()

    fun setData(user: User) {
        //Logged fine
        Timber.e("User setted")
        data.value = user
    }

    fun getData(): LiveData<User> {
        if (data.value == null) {
            val user = User()
            user.coins = 200
            data.value = user
        }
        //Logged fine, "false"
        Timber.e("User getted")
        Timber.e("Is user == null? %s", (data.value == null).toString())
        return data
    }

    override fun takeCoins(value: Int) {
          //Specially commented it 
//        getCoins(value)
    }
}
```

---

**UPD:**

I make some changes to prevent crush - make userViewModel nullable(update **PacksFragment** code on the top).

But userViewModel is always null when i call `updateToolbar()`. Main thing fragment not removed/deleted/invisible/..., it's active fragment with button which called `updateToolbar()` function.

Comment: Your `updateToolbar()` method gets called from Presenter when your `Fragment` has detached state. In such case, ViewModelProvider can't get your fragment due to it's detached and though throws error. Recommended way in MVVM is that create `ViewModel` instance inside `onCreate()` of your Activity/Fragment. Then reuse that object everywhere.

Comment: I tryed like you say, but i failed. I update my question.

Comment: Make it nullable instead : `private var userViewModel: UserViewModel? = Null` and then access like `userViewModel?.getData()`. This won't crash and won't get called if **null**.

Comment: I do it right when you write it, and now my UserViewModel is null when i call `updateToolbar()`. How can it be if i initialize it inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: It's because, ViewModels are attached to Activity/Fragment lifecycle. So, if fragment is not attached, it will provide null for ViewModel also.

Comment: It looks like i don't understand smth basic. When function called, i see fragment on the screen. It's not gone or smth, just active fragment with button who called function. How it can be deatach?

Comment: You're mixing two development architectures MVVM and Clean together. Don't do that, try using only one instead.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your issue?